# Home page error - How to solve Element 'block', attribute 'destination': The attribute 'destination' is not allowed

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

My homepage getting the following error,

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'destination': The attribute 'destination' is not allowed.
Line: 953

Element 'block', attribute 'destination': The attribute 'destination' is not allowed.
Line: 988


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'destination': The attribute 'destination' is not allowed.
Line: 953

Element 'block', attribute 'destination': The attribute 'destination' is not allowed.
Line: 988

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:xs...', &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#0000000058d80d55000000006a5c4095#, array(), NULL, 'C:/xampp/htdocs/...', '%message%\nLine: ...') called at [vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php:121]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Framewor...', array('<layout xmlns:xs...', &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#0000000058d80d55000000006a5c4095#, array(), NULL, 'C:/xampp/htdocs/...', '%message%\nLine: ...')) called at [vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php:66]
```

How to solve this error?

Log error:

```
[2021-03-01 04:07:53] report.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_5161502e12d09aab87e298d5a11fd6c6e_page_layout_merged and handles default, cms_index_index, cms_page_view, cms_index_index_id_home, am_mega_menu_layout: Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'block', attribute 'destination': The attribute 'destination' is not allowed.
Line: 953

Element 'block', attribute 'destination': The attribute 'destination' is not allowed.
Line: 988
 [] []
[2021-03-01 04:07:53] report.ERROR: Element 'block', attribute 'destination': The attribute 'destination' is not allowed.
Line: 953

Element 'block', attribute 'destination': The attribute 'destination' is not allowed.
Line: 988
 [] []
```

Comment: In one of your custom layout  you might have used 'destination' attribute with <block> tag which is not supported. 'destination' attribute works only with <move> tag.

Comment: @LokeshNaik Thank You, after removing the destination from the block it's working, thank you.